# Internet connection not recognised

Tags: windows-7, internet

I'm having some weird internet issues since today.

It says it is connected to the internet, but it doesn't mention the connection's name. Though it normally does that.

When i I open the network overview (literally translated, don't know if this is the name) it says I am connected to the internet and to the rest of my domain. Ping works, to websites and in my domain. But when I try to acces a website trough a browser it times out.

I have tried all automatic solutions from windows, as well as resetting my router, reattaching my cable, etc.

I'm using W7, router is a linksys, the older blue ones, 802.11g

[image]

The cable is a 1Gbps one, the adapter is a realtek 8168D/8111D

Comment: I also suspect a virus might be the cause..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your browser's proxy settings.  Various malwares drop a little proxy server onto your machine and configure your browser to use it.

In IE the settings are under `Internet Options | Connecitons tab | Lan Settings`

In FF the settings are under `Options | Advanced | Netowrk | Settings.`

If you see that your browser is set to use a proxy, start scanning for viruses.